# Javascript: How to auto scroll down in elements in phone, when phone keyboard will appear and the element's height will resize to smaller?

Tags: javascript, html, autoscroll

**(keep scroll down while resizing)**

Hey guys,
I had a problem and I solved it by myself,
but I'm not sure my solution is the main solution or not!
I wanna go to the right way to solve my problem --
so...
This is my HTML:

```
<textarea id="textarea" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></textarea>
```

And this is my JS:

```
var textarea=document.getElementById("textarea");
        var scrollDown=true;
        var defaultHeight=textarea.clientHeight;
        for(var n=0; n<100; n++) //auto add 100 lines in textarea!
            {
                textarea.value+="Line "+n+"\n";
                if(n==99)
                    {
                        textarea.value+="Line 100 (Final Line)";
                    }
            }
        setInterval(function(){ //can this interval replace with anything?
            if(scrollDown==true)
                {
                    textarea.scrollTop=textarea.scrollHeight;
                    scrollDown=false;
                }
        },0);
        setInterval(function(){ //can this interval replace with anything?
            if(defaultHeight!=textarea.clientHeight)
                {
                    scrollDown=true;
                    defaultHeight=textarea.clientHeight;
                }
        },0);
```

So, as you can see, my codes working correctly without any problem, but my **question is: Am I in the right way? Is there another way to solve this problem without using Intervals?**

*Please someone answer to me!*